# URLConnection invalid phpsessid

Tags: java, urlconnection

I want to execute some post but this post required PHPSESSID and one parameter.
If i take this parameters from browser and execute in my code all work correct.
Unfortunately when i use my code to get page content and cookie for "PHPSESSID" and parameter and use this to execute post, it doesn't work.

Example
PHPSESSID and param value we can obtain when we go in browser to 'http://www.kreskowkazone.pl/odcinki-online_rick-i-morty-2013_7'
PHPSESSID we can get from cookie and value for param "o" is a long number in icon/link play for "openload.io" (code look like this 181774:bb19d7426f8eda85ba82265a01eda9c7 but it change).
Whan we use this param in the code all works fine we see iframe html

**Code to execute post**

```
public void sendPostTest(String param, String phpSESSID) throws IOException {
URL url = new URL("http://www.kreskowkazone.pl/odcinki_emb");
Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
params.put("o", param);


StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> p : params.entrySet()) {
    if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(p.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
    postData.append('=');
    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(p.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
}
byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.kreskowkazone.pl");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html, */*; q=0.01");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.kreskowkazone.pl/odcinki-online_rick-i-morty-2013_24");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));

conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", phpSESSID);

conn.setRequestProperty("DNT", "1");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; ) {
    System.out.print((char) c);
}
```

}

Unfortunately when i take this param by my code i don't get any error and i don't see iframe.
To get page content and PHPSESSID I use this code.

```
public class CustomCookieManager {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        getPageContent("http://www.kreskowkazone.pl/odcinki-online_rick-i-morty-2013_7");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void getPageContent(String pageUrl) throws IOException {
    CookieManager ckman = new java.net.CookieManager();
    ckman.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(ckman);
    URL url = new URL(pageUrl);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.getContent();
    String html = getHtml(connection);
    CookieStore ckStore = ckman.getCookieStore();
    List<HttpCookie> cks = ckStore.getCookies();
    for (HttpCookie ck : cks) {
            System.out.println("PHPSESSID=" + ck.getValue());
            System.out.println(html);
    }
}

public static String getHtml(URLConnection conn) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(inputLine);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```

}

I know PHPSESSID is related with param value because when i take PHPSESSID from one browser and parameter value from other browser
post doesn't work (no error no iframe).

My question is, is it posible that my CookieManager return cookie and PHPSESSID not for page which i'm reading in CustomCookieManager?
I tried the same example from HttpUnit with no result.

Comment: You should not set the HOST or CONTENT-LENGTH headers, or do both of `getContent()` and `getInputStream()`. You seem to be assuming that all the cookies are PHPSESSID cookies.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't matter do i set or not HOST and CONTENT-LENGTH. 
I can call only getInputStream() it doesn't work. As i mentioned with data from browser all works fine and i'm talking here about 
parameter value and cookie which contains only PHPSESSID. I created simple java selenium test but this test need a browser.
If i use data returned from selenium all works fine.
But as i mentioned this test using browser and i don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

Try only using the same PHPSESSID as the one in your browser for every request, i was supposed to comment this but i wasn't allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Wells

I could but it will be one-off solution because PHPSESSID or number which is sending as parameter expired after some time.
After about half hour PHPSESSID and parameter are invalid (i don't see iframe html).

I can't use PHPSESSID from browser and parameter value returned by my java code because it's doesn't work. 
It looks like generating parameter value depending on PHPSESSID.

I start thinking that my CookieManager is not releated with page which content i take in CustomCookieManager. 
Is it possible that CookieManager joust return some PHPSESSID which is not related with page i downloaded.

I start thinking that page have some javascript which change something so i use HttpUnit but with no result.

Maybe it's impossible maybe it's some kind of security for the page but this CookieManager bites me.

Comment: Did you find solution for that?